# Making sense of the canonical anti-commutation relations for Dirac spinors

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, quantization, anticommutator

When doing scalar QFT one typically imposes the famous 'canonical commutation relations' on the field and canonical momentum: $$[\phi(\vec x),\pi(\vec y)]=i\delta^3 (\vec x-\vec y)$$ at equal times ($x^0=y^0$). It is easy (though tedious) to check that this implies a commutation relation for the creation/annihilation operators
$$[a(\vec k),a^\dagger(\vec k')]=(2\pi)^32\omega\delta^3(\vec k-\vec k') $$

When considering the Dirac (spinor) field, it is usual (see e.g. [page 107 of Tong's notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf) or Peskin & Schroeder's book) to proceed analogously (replacing commutators with anticommutators, of course). We postulate 
\begin{equation}
\{\Psi(\vec x),\Psi^\dagger(\vec y)\}=i\delta^3(\vec x -\vec y) 
\end{equation}
and, from them, derive the usual relations for the creation/annihilation operators.

I'd always accepted this and believed the calculations presented in the above-mentioned sources, but I suddenly find myself in doubt: Do these relations even make any sense for the Dirac field? Since $\Psi$ is a 4-component spinor, I don't really see how one can possibly make sense out of the above equation: Isn't $\Psi\Psi^\dagger$ a $4\times 4$ matrix, while $\Psi^\dagger\Psi$ is a number?! Do we have to to the computation (spinor-)component by component? If this is the case, then I think I see some difficulties (in the usual computations one needs an identity which depends on the 4-spinors actually being 4-spinors). Are these avoided somehow? A detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

As a follow-up, consider the following: One usually encounters terms like this in the calculation:
$$u^\dagger \dots a a^\dagger\dots u- u\dots a^\dagger a \dots u^\dagger $$ Even if one accepts that an equation like $\{\Psi,\Psi^\dagger\}$ makes sense, most sources simply 'pull the $u,\ u^\dagger$ out of the commutators' to get (anti)commutators of only the creation/annihilation operators. How is this justified?

**EDIT**: I have just realized that the correct commutation relation perhaps substitutes $\Psi^\dagger$ with $\bar \Psi$ (this may circumvent any issue that arises in a componentwise calculation). Please feel free to use either in an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I got your point. In the case of Dirac spinors the anticommutation rules work by components (see for example Peskin & Schroeder p.58): $$\{ \psi_\alpha(\textbf{x}),\psi_\beta^\dagger(\textbf{y}) \} = \delta_{\alpha \beta} \delta^3(\textbf{x}-\textbf{y})$$ so you *do* have a 4x4 matrix on RHS. Was this your question?

Comment: @glance The computations *are* componentwise? This is not obvious to me (the 'standard sources' certainly don't explicitly display these indices), although I already mentioned it as a possibility. If you can carry out the computation this way (avoiding some perhaps minor problems that I foresee) and post it as an answer, I'd be more than happy to accept it!

Comment: See Peskin and Schroeder  eq. 3.86 for verification that the relation is component-wise.

Comment: @joshphysics *damnit*, I was looking at 3.89 and didn't see any components, and freaked out. I guess that settles it...

Comment: Somebody should post that as an answer! (FWIW I came to the same conclusion from Tong's notes)

Comment: @Danu of course, but to what computation are you referring exactly? The derivation of the commutation rules for the creation/operators from the canonical commutation rules (your first equation) or the equal-time (anti)commutation relations (your second one)? Also, i believe the reference in P&S is 3.102, at 3.89 they are showing that the commutators does not work for Dirac spinors (at least in my edition)

Comment: @glance I think you should be given the honors, and just include a reference to P&K substantiate your comment.  Agreed that 3.89 is inappropriate.

Comment: @glance deriving the CCR for the creation/annihilation operators of the Dirac field would be more than satisfactory.

Comment: @joshphysics Of course, 3.89 is not the calculation for $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ but it's the only explicit calculation, so that's why I was looking there ;)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17893/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One usually *starts* from the CCR for the creation/annihilation operators and derives from there the commutation rules for the fields.
However, one can start from either (see for example [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88731/58382) about this).
Suppose we want then to start from the equal-time anticommutation rules for a Dirac field $\psi_\alpha(x)$:
$$ \tag{1} \{ \psi_\alpha(\textbf{x}), \psi_\beta^\dagger(\textbf{y}) \} = \delta_{\alpha \beta} \delta^3(\textbf{x}-\textbf{y}),$$
where $\psi_\alpha(x)$ has an expansion of the form
$$ \tag{2} \psi_\alpha(x) = \int \frac{d^3 p} {(2\pi)^3 2E_\textbf{p}} \sum_s\left\{ c_s(p) [u_s(p)]_\alpha e^{-ipx} + d_s^\dagger(p) [v_s(p)]_\alpha e^{ipx} \right\}$$
or more concisely
$$ \psi(x) = \int d\tilde{p} \left( c_p u_p e^{-ipx} + d_p^\dagger v_p e^{ipx} \right), $$

and we want to *derive* the CCR for the creation/annihilation operators:
$$ \tag{3} \{ a_s(p), a_{s'}^\dagger(q) \} = (2\pi)^3 (2 E_p) \delta_{s s'}\delta^3(\textbf{p}-\textbf{q}).$$
To do this, we want to express $a_s(p)$ in terms of $\psi(x)$. We have:
$$ \tag{4} a_s(\textbf{k}) = i \bar{u}_s(\textbf{k}) \int d^3 x \left[ e^{ikx}  \partial_0 \psi(x) - \psi(x) \partial_0 e^{ikx} \right]\\
= i \bar{u}_s(\textbf{k}) \int d^3 x \,\,  e^{ikx}  \overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_0} \psi(x) $$
$$ \tag{5} a_s^\dagger (\textbf{k}) = -i \bar{u}_s(\textbf{k}) \int d^3 x \left[ e^{-ikx}  \partial_0 \psi(x) - \psi(x) \partial_0 e^{-ikx} \right] \\
=-i \bar{u}_s(\textbf{k}) \int d^3 x \,\, e^{-ikx}  \overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_0} \psi(x) $$
which you can verify by pulling the expansion **(2)** into **(4)** and **(5)**.
Note that these hold for any $x_0$ on the RHS.

Now you just have to insert in the anticommutator on the LHS of **(3)** these expressions and use **(1)** (I can expand a little on this calculation if you need it).

> most sources simply 'pull the $u, u^\dagger$ out of the commutators' to get (anti)commutators of only the creation/annihilation operators. How is this justified?

There is a big difference between a polarization spinor $u$ and a creation/destruction operator $c,c^\dagger$.

For fixed polarization $s$ and momentum $\textbf{p}$, $u_s(\textbf{p})$ is a four-component spinor, meaning that $u_s(\textbf{p})_\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ for each $\alpha=1,2,3,4$. 
Conversely, for fixed polarization $s$ and momentum $\textbf{p}$, $c_s(\textbf{p})$ is an operator in the [Fock space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space). *Not* just a number, which makes meaningful wondering about (anti)commutators.

Comment: By "double arrow" do you mean $\Longleftrightarrow$ or two right arrows ontop of each other?

Comment: I mean the arrow which points on both sides.. the symbol used to indicate a derivative on the right minus a derivative on the left: in $ a \bar{\partial}_\mu b \equiv a \partial_\mu b - (\partial_\mu a) b$ the symbol that would normally be used instead of the bar in $\bar{\partial}$

Comment: `\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial}` $\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial}$

Comment: A single lined arrow that points both ways is `\leftrightarrow`: $\leftrightarrow$. You can put that over by using `\overset{up}{down}`: $\overset{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_\mu}$.